# Красивый MessageBox

Tags: c#, wpf, style, messagebox, popup

Возможно ли изменить стандартный стиль MessageBox на более красивый? Чтобы не создавать новое окно в проекте (просто мне кажется что это как-то не правильно). И если не сложно то как затемнить окно при вызове MessageBox.Show? чтобы не создавать чёрный rectangle на всё окно с прозрачностью на 50%

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: MessageBox - функция WinAPI и она не принимает параметров для таких украшательств, как и MessageBoxEx и MessageBoxIndirect. Соответственно, стандартный MessageBox не перекроить.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов то есть придётся делать как я в принципе и думал?

Comment: Да, придется рисовать свой диалог наверняка.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов ну тогда ладно, а вот как насчёт второго вопроса? ))

Comment: Затемнение это и есть черный прямоугольник с прозрачностью. Никаких чудес.

Comment: @Alex_Rudenkiy увы не знаю: не люблю и не умею гуйню.

Comment: Вручную, всё вручную. Открыть окно, дождаться нажатия на кнопку, закрыть окно.